# Why my Python 2.7 envs only works when I start the terminal by Anaconda Navigator?

Tags: python, cmd, pycharm, anaconda, prompt

All python 2* envs I created doesn't really start when activating dicrectly from cmd. When activating this way, there is no error message on the prompt, all seem to be ok, then I run python 2 scripts and they doesn't work. Only way I found to do it is by starting the terminal from Anaconda Navigador. This also happens with Pycharm: code doesn't works when running py2 scripts in Pycharm WITHOUT having started it from Anaconda Navigator.

Computer programming and configuration is not my professional area, so if the answer relates to configuring path, or system variables, please be kind giving me a "for dummie" explanation.

I'm using Windows 10.

Thanks!

Comment: are you sourcing the conda environment from the command line? for pycharm you need to tell it your python interpreter is whatever is your conda environment pyhon which is a bit tricky

Comment: also what happens if you source the environments and then do pip freeze

Comment: Yes, I am. And doing it seems not to really activate the env. Then I do this: open Anaconda Navigator > open Pycharm by Anaconda Navigator. Then the env is automatically activated and all works well. But these steps are annoying me!